# How can I use SFINAE to distinguish MyMap, std::map and std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, compilation, stl, metaprogramming, sfinae

I want to make a struct that can  use any implementation of maps.
Let's call it a `MapHolder`. Currently, it looks like this:

```cpp
template<template<class, class, class...> class MapType>
struct MapHolder
{
  MapType<int, int> m_map;
}
```

And that would work with any map.

But I want to use custom comparator/allocator/hash when possible as well:

```cpp
 // Works only with std::unordered_map
 MapType<int, int, my::hash<int>> m_map;
```

Or

```cpp
 // Works only with std::map
 MapType<int, int, std::greater<>> m_map;
```

And it will compile only with one of the classes.

Can't SFINAE help me to make compiler choose the most appropriate declaration (i.e. first for `MapHolder<MyMap>`, second for `MapHolder<std::unordered_map>` and so on)?

Comment: Why SFINAE? Can you use _partial template specialization_?

Comment: I didn't get where you're providing the custom comparator/hash/allocator?

Comment: SFINAE, because I didn't know about partial template scecialization :) I'm quite new in the world of metaprogramming.

Comment: It's inside the `MapHolder`. I want to use custom allocator for STL containers and default for `MyMap` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *partial template specialization* here. Something as:

```
template<template<class, class, class...> class MapType>
struct MapHolder
{
private:
   template <typename> struct ThirdArgument;

   template <typename K,  typename V, typename C, typename A>
   struct ThirdArgument<std::map<K, V, C, A>>
   {
      using type = std::greater<K>;
   };

   template <typename K,  typename V, typename H, typename E, typename A>
   struct ThirdArgument<std::unordered_map<K, V, H, E, A>>
   {
      using type = std::hash<K>;
   };

public:
   MapType<int, int,
      typename ThirdArgument<MapType<int, int>>::type
   > m_map;
};

int main()
{
    MapHolder<std::map> m1;
    MapHolder<std::unordered_map> m2;
}
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/mEaFZv.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But that one won't work with class `template<class K, class V>MyMap` that accepts only 2 templates (assume that not everybody allows to customize hash or comparator in their class). Can't we choose not just one argument of declaration, but whole declaration instead?

Comment: @hououinkyouma Then, you can use partial specialization for the specification of the whole container. Such as `using type = std::map<K, V, std::greater<K>, A>;` for `std::map`, `using type = std::unordered_map<K, V, std::hash<K>, E, A>;` for `std::unordered_map`, and something as `using type = MyMap<K, V>;` for your map.

Comment: Could you, please, give me an example? I've tried it and get some type/value mismatch error.